# Getting the amount of followers an artist has on Spotify

Tags: api, google-apps-script, spotify

I used to be able to import the amount of followers an artist has on spotify into a google sheet (tracking multiple artists)by web scraping with the IMPORTXML funtion, but I can no longer do it now that Spotify no longer allows unauthenticated calls.  I assume this can be done using API and a Google Apps Script, but I have no idea where to start.  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: you can try to use official Spotify API https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/user-guide/

Comment: I've looked in to it, but I'm still not sure how I'd go about getting that info in way that's conducive to continually updating spreadsheet

Answer (score 0):

Good place to start is to setup project trigger to run specific function to update the sheet. This can be done in spreadsheet script editor. See image below.

[image]